# In cuda, thread indexes are not fully shown in the kernel function

Tags: c++, linux, cuda

I am writing code and recently, I found some error. The simplified version is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#define DEBUG 1

inline void check_cuda_errors(const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error at %s:%i: %s\n", filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(-1);
    }
#endif
}


__global__ void make_input_matrix_zp()
{
    unsigned int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    printf("col: %d (%d*%d+%d)   row: %d (%d*%d+%d)   \n", col, blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x, row, blockIdx.y, blockDim.y, threadIdx.y);
}



int main()
{
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16, 1);
    dim3 gridDim(6, 6, 1);
    make_input_matrix_zp<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>();
    //check_cuda_errors(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    return 0;
}
```

The first inline function is for checking the error in the cuda. 
The second kernel function simply calculates current thread's index written in 'row' and 'col' and print these values. I guess there are no problem in inline function since it is from other reliable source.

The problem is, when I run the program, it does not execute kernel function even though it is called in the main function. However, if I delete the comment notation '//' in front of the

```
check_cuda_error
```

the program seems to enter the kernel function and it shows some printed value by printf function. But, it does not shows full combination of 'col' and 'row' indexes. In detail, the 'blockDim.y' does not change much. It only shows values of 4 and 5, but not 0, 1, 2, 3.

What I do not understand first.
As far as I know, the 'gridDim' means the dimension of the blocks. That means the block indexes have combination of (0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)... and so on. Also the size of the each block is 16 by 16. However, if you run this program, it does not show full combination. I just shows several combinations and it ends.

What I do not understand second.
Why the kernel function is dependent to the function named 'check_cuda_errors'? When this function exists, the program at least runs although imperfectly. However, when this error checking function is commented, the kernel function does not show any printed values.

This is very simple code but I couldn't find the problem for several days. Is there anything that I missed? Or do I know something wrong?

My working environment is like this.
"GeForce GT 630"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUDA GPU `printf` subsystem relies on a FIFO buffer to store printed output. If your output exceeds the size of the buffer, some or all of the previous content of the FIFO buffer will be overwritten by subsequent output. This is what will be happening in this case.

You can query and change the size of the buffer using the runtime API with [cudaDeviceGetLimit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g720e159aeb125910c22aa20fe9611ec2) and [cudaDeviceSetLimit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g05956f16eaa47ef3a4efee84563ccb7d). If your device has the resources available to expand the limit, you should be able to see all the output your code emits.

As an aside, relying on the kernel `printf` feature for anything other than simple diagnostics or lightweight debugging, is a terrible idea, and you have probably just proven to yourself that you should be looking at other methods of verifying the correctness of your code.

---

Regarding your second question, the `printf` buffer is flushed to output only when the host synchronizes with the device. For example, with a call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize`, `cudaThreadSynchronize`, `cudaMemcpy`, and others (see [B.17.2 Limitations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#limitations) of the Formatted Output appendix).

When `check_cuda_errors` is uncommented, calling `cudaThreadSynchronize` is what triggers the buffer to be printed. When it is commented, the main thread simply terminates before the kernel gets to run to completion, and nothing else happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand my first question may related to the buffer issue, however is the second question also related to this buffer related problem?